# Regex How to Escape multiple slashes usign mongoose and javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, mongoose

I need to build a Javascript RegEx to look for some pattern in a mongo database using mongoose.

Data stored in database:

```
\\\\12345
\\\\12345\\1
\\\\12345\\1\\1
\\\\12345\\1\\2
\\\\12345\\1\\3
\\\\12345\\1\\4
\\\\12345\\2
\\\\12345\\2\\1
\\\\12345\\2\\2
\\\\12345\\2\\3
\\\\12345\\2\\4
\\\\12345\\3
\\\\12345\\3\\1
\\\\12345\\3\\2
\\\\12345\\3\\3
\\\\12345\\3\\4
```

In the real data the numbers are ObjectIds.
My current searchs are:

Look for root id´s: `\\\\`: Shall return all elements

Look for group id´s: `\\\\12345`: Shall return all elements under 12345

Look for subgroup id´s: `\\\\12345\\1`: Shall return all elements starting with group     `\\\12345\\1`

My regex:

```
let search = "\\12345\1";

let filter = search.replace('\', '\\');
let regex = new RegExp("^" + text);

return MyModel.find({ path: regex }).exec();
```

My regex is not working properly. Considering javascript treats duplicates slashes as one as well as mongoose and the Regex, I´m confused about the right way of doing this.

Comment: It seems it sends regex to MongoDB for execution so how about `path: /^\Q\\\\12345\\1\E/`?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this:

```
([\\]{4})(\d*)([\\]{2}\d+)?([\\]{2}\d+)?
```

See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/VnJUmP/2)

You should be able to do an if statement surrounding the capture groups to satisfy the rest:

```
if(matches[1]){
  if(matches[2]){
    if(matches[3]){
      if(matches[4]){
         // do another thing when there are multiple subgroups (undefined in your question, but appears in your examples)
      } else {
         // return all starting with group \\\\12345\\1
      }
    }else{
      // return all under 12345
    }
  }else{
    // return all elements
  }
}
```